# Established TCP connection but socket doesn't send/recv data

Tags: perl, sockets, tcp, netcat

I'm writing a simple TCP client and server Perl script. 
As of now I verify the 3 way TCP handshake using wireshark, and the connection is established.
But when i try to send or recv data nothing happens.

Questions:

1) the major difference between the client and the server is only that the server has an added LISTEN parameter which enables it to listen for incoming connections ?

2)Are there any steps missing between recv and displaying the data?

3)Shouldn't atleast the hardcoded string "$response" be sent when the program executes the while loop the first time?

4)How do shutdown($sock,1) and sleep(1) differ in this implementation? Is it okay to let the socket sleep or should I use shutdown($sock,1) to signal to the client/server that data has been sent ?

on inspecting the status of the connection in wireshark, i've noticed that only the handshake takes place. there is no data exchanged at all. So im pretty sure the problem lies somewhere on writing to the socket and reading data from the socket (using the keyboard or hardcoded strings).

Any help would be really appreciated.

The client is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use IO::Socket;
use Getopt::Long;
#$IP_addr = $ARGV[0];
#$tgt_port = $ARG[1];

#netcat client

$port = 9040;
$sock = IO::Socket::INET->new( PeerAddr => 'localhost',
                               PeerPort => $port,
                               LocalPort => 9000,               
                               Proto     => 'tcp')
                               or die "\nunable to bind on localhost : $port...";

while ($sock){
    #Get the clients IP and port number 
        $client_IP = $sock -> peerhost();
    #$client_IP = 'localhost';
        $client_port = $sock -> peerport();
        print "\n Connected to $client_IP $client_port \n";

    #Reading from socket
    $data;  
    $sock ->recv($data, 1024);
    print $data;

    #writing to  socket
    $sock->autoflush(1);
    $response = "response: OK recvd\n" ;
    $sock->send($response);
    shutdown($sock,1);

}

$sock -> close();
```

The server is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use IO::Socket;
use Getopt::Long;

#$IP_addr = $ARGV[0];
#$tgt_port = $ARG[1];

#netcat server
$port = 9040;
$sock = IO::Socket::INET->new( Listen    => 1,
                               LocalAddr => 'localhost',
                               LocalPort => $port,
                               Proto     => 'tcp')
                               or die "\nunable to bind on localhost : $port...";

while ($sock){
    print "\nListening on port $port ...\n";
        $sock  = $sock -> accept();
    #Get the clients IP and port number 
        $client_IP = $sock->peerhost();
        $client_port = $sock->peerport();
        print "\n Connected from $client_IP $client_port \n";

    #Reading from socket
    $data ->recv($sock, 1024);
    print $data;

    #writing to  socket
    $sock->autoflush(1);
    $response = "oohlalala" ;
    $sock -> send($response);
    shutdown($sock, 1);

}

$sock -> close();
```

Comment: I see at least two problems with your code: (1) you use `recv` & `send` on a TCP stream instead of an UDP socket, (2) both server & client start with `recv` and wait forever, because the other side isn't sending anyting

Comment: Plus you overwrite `$sock` inside the server loop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [IO::Socket](https://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Socket.html):

> As of VERSION 1.18 all IO::Socket objects have autoflush turned on by
>   default. This was not the case with earlier releases.

Perl version 2.0 was released in 1988.  You are most likely using perl version 5.x.

> **1)** the major difference between the client and the server is only that
>   the server has an added LISTEN parameter which enables it to listen
>   for incoming connections ?

According to the [docs](http://%20https://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Socket/INET.html):

> If Listen is defined then a listen socket is created...

A listen socket can call `accept()`.  If a regular socket calls accept(), accept() returns undef.

> **accept()**
>
> In a scalar context the new socket is returned, or undef upon failure.
>   In a list context a two-element array is returned containing the new
>   socket and the peer address; the list will be empty upon failure.
>
> https://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Socket.html

Here is a [nice, short, basic description of sockets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/definition.html).

Your server code probably hides some of what's going on.  It would be more illustrative if it was written like this:

```
$server_socket = IO::Socket::INET(.....);
...
...
my $client_socket = $server_socket->accept();
...
...
```

There are two different sockets.  accept() returns a new socket for the server and the client to communicate with, so the original server socket can keep listening for client connections.

> **2)** Are there any steps missing between recv and displaying the data?

Depending on what you're doing, you might want to get rid of the characters that mark the end of the data, which the code would have used to signal the other side that it should stop trying to read more data from the socket.

Receiving the data is the tricky part.  An agreed upon protocol must be used by both the client and the server to avoid deadlock, which is when both the client and the server are waiting for the other side to send data.     In the example below, I employ a "line oriented" protocol where one side stops reading from the socket when it reads a newline.  In networking, by convention a newline is considered to be "\r\n", which represents the ascii characters `carriage return` and `line feed`, but to avoid any type of automatic "\n" translations on various OS's, the socket library uses the actual ascii codes: 13 and 10, which in hex notation is: "\x0D\x0A".

server.pl:

```
use strict;  
use warnings; 
use 5.020;
use autodie;
use Data::Dumper;

use IO::Socket::INET;
use Socket qw( :crlf );  # "\x0D\x0A" constants CRLF and $CRLF

my $host = 'localhost';
my $port = 15_678;

my $server_socket = IO::Socket::INET->new(
        Listen    => 5,
        LocalPort => $port,
        LocalAddr => $host,
        Proto     => 'tcp',
        ReuseAddr => 1,
        ReusePort => 1
);

say "Server listening on port: $port\n";

while (my $client_socket = $server_socket->accept() ) {

    my $client_ip = $client_socket->peerhost();
    my $client_port = $client_socket->peerport();
    say "Connection from $client_ip:$client_port";

    {
        local $/ = CRLF; # $/ is the input record separator, which is "\n" 
                         #by default. Both <$INFILE> and getline() read up to
                         #and including the input record separator.
        while(my $line = $client_socket->getline) { #Blocks until CRLF is read 
                                                 #from the socket or the other 
                                                 #side closes the socket.
            chomp $line; #chomp() removes input record separator from end of line.
            say "Server received: $line";

            my $response = reverse $line;
            $client_socket->send("$response$CRLF");

            say "Server sent: $response";
        }

    }  #Here $/ is restored to whatever it was before this parenthesized block. 
       #That is what declaring a variable as local does.

    say "-" x 30;

    #Execution arrives here after the client closes the socket:
    $client_socket->shutdown(2);  #Send signals to other side of socket.
                                  #Not necessary in this example because other threads  
                                  #aren't also reading from the socket.
    $client_socket->close();  #Close the filehandle associated with the socket.
}
```

Note that just like when reading a file, getline will return everything it has read so far when it receives an eof signal, and for the next iteration of the while loop getline will return undef causing the while loop to terminate.

client.pl:

```
use strict;  
use warnings; 
use 5.020;
use autodie;
use Data::Dumper;

use IO::Socket::INET;
use Socket qw( :crlf ); #\x0D\x0A constants CRLF and $CRLF 

my $port = 15_678;

my @lines = (
    "hello world",
    "goodbye mars",
);

my $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new("localhost:$port");

for my $line(@lines){

    my $server_ip = $sock->peerhost();
    my $server_port = $sock->peerport();
    say "Connected to $server_ip:$server_port";

    $sock->send("$line$CRLF");
    say "Client sent: $line";

    my $response;
    {
        local $/ = CRLF;
        $response = $sock->getline();
        chomp $response;
    }  

    say "Client received: $response";
    say '-' x 30;

}

#Tell the server that no more data is coming from this client:
$sock->shutdown(2);  #Send signals to other side of socket.
$sock->close();  #Close the filehandle associated with the socket.
```

After running the client program twice...

Server output:

```
Server listening on port: 15678

Connection from 127.0.0.1:56085
Server received: hello world
Server sent: dlrow olleh
Server received: goodbye mars
Server sent: sram eybdoog
------------------------------
Connection from 127.0.0.1:56096
Server received: hello world
Server sent: dlrow olleh
Server received: goodbye mars
Server sent: sram eybdoog
------------------------------
```

Client output:

```
$ perl client.pl 
Connected to 127.0.0.1:15678
Client sent: hello world
Client received: dlrow olleh
------------------------------
Connected to 127.0.0.1:15678
Client sent: goodbye mars
Client received: sram eybdoog
------------------------------
$ perl client.pl 
Connected to 127.0.0.1:15678
Client sent: hello world
Client received: dlrow olleh
------------------------------
Connected to 127.0.0.1:15678
Client sent: goodbye mars
Client received: sram eybdoog
------------------------------
$
```

> **3)** Shouldn't atleast the hardcoded string "$response" be sent when the
>   program executes the while loop the first time?

Yes, all statements in a while loop will have executed *after* the first loop has finished executing--but when a statement higher up in the loop is blocking, then the send will never execute.

> **4)** How do shutdown($sock,1) and sleep(1) differ in this implementation? Is it okay to let the socket sleep or should I use
>   shutdown($sock,1) to signal to the client/server that data has been
>   sent ?

I'm not sure how shutdown() and sleep() are related in any way. sleep() stops your code from executing for the specified time, while shutdown() sends something to the other side of a socket.

"Closing the socket", i.e. calling `shutdown()`, to mark the end of the data is another protocol that you can adopt.  It makes things pretty easy: one side just continues to read from the socket in some sort of read statement, and when the other side closes the socket, the read will return.  Here's an example:

server.pl:

```
use strict;  
use warnings; 
use 5.020;
use autodie;
use Data::Dumper;

use IO::Socket::INET;

my $host = 'localhost';
my $port = 15_678;

my $server_socket = IO::Socket::INET->new(
        Listen    => 5,
        LocalPort => $port,
        LocalAddr => $host,
        Proto     => 'tcp',
        ReuseAddr => 1,
        ReusePort => 1
);

say "Server listening on port: $port\n";

while (my $client_socket = $server_socket->accept() ) {

    my $client_ip = $client_socket->peerhost();
    my $client_port = $client_socket->peerport();
    say "Connection from $client_ip:$client_port";

    my $data;
    {
        local $/ = undef;  #This input record separtor will never be found...
        $data = <$client_socket>;  #...so this reads everything--including newlines--until it gets an eof signal.
    }

    say "Server received: $data";
    my $response = reverse $data;
    $client_socket->send($response);

    $client_socket->shutdown(2); #Doesn't close filehandle -- merely sends signals.
    $client_socket->close();  ##Close the filehandle associated with the socket.

    say "Server sent: $response";
    say "-" x 30;
}
```

client.pl:

```
use strict;  
use warnings; 
use 5.020;
use autodie;
use Data::Dumper;

use IO::Socket::INET;

my $port = 15_678;

my @data = (
    "hello \n world",   #Now newlines are in the data
    "goodbye \n mars",
);

for my $data (@data){
    my $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new("localhost:$port");
    my $server_ip = $sock->peerhost();
    my $server_port = $sock->peerport();
    say "Connected to $server_ip:$server_port";

    $sock->send($data);
    say "Client sent: $data";
    $sock->shutdown(1);

    my  $response;
    { 
        local $/ = undef;  #This input record separtor will never be found...
        $response = <$sock>;  ##...so this reads everything--including newlines--until it gets an eof signal.
    }
    $sock->shutdown(0);

    $sock->close();

    say "Client received: $response";
    say '-' x 30;

}
```

Server output:

```
Server listening on port: 15678

Connection from 127.0.0.1:53139
Server received: hello 
 world
Server sent: dlrow 
 olleh
------------------------------
Connection from 127.0.0.1:53140
Server received: goodbye 
 mars
Server sent: sram 
 eybdoog
------------------------------
```

Client output:

```
Connected to 127.0.0.1:15678
Client sent: hello 
 world
Client received: dlrow 
 olleh
------------------------------
Connected to 127.0.0.1:15678
Client sent: goodbye 
 mars
Client received: sram 
 eybdoog
------------------------------
```

Comment: thanks @7stud for the detailed explanation. I really appreciate it

Comment: @baconSoda, You are welcome.  I changed my first example because the server was sort of doubling down with my line oriented protocol: the server was also closing the socket after finding the end of line marker.  You don't need two markers to signal the end of the line.  Now, the difference between the line oriented protocol and the close the socket protocol is more stark.

Answer (score 2):

Code for the server (tested with telnet localhost 9040):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Socket::INET;

my $port = 9040;
my $listen = IO::Socket::INET->new(Listen    => 1,
                                   LocalPort => $port,
                                   Proto     => 'tcp',
                                   ReuseAddr => 1,
                                   ReusePort => 1);
while ($listen) {
    print "\nListening on port $port ...\n";
    my $sock  = $listen->accept();
    my $client_IP = $sock->peerhost();
    my $client_port = $sock->peerport();
    print "\n Connected from $client_IP $client_port \n";

    my $data;
    $sock->recv($data, 1024);
    print $data;

    #writing to  socket
    $sock->autoflush(1);
    my $response = "oohlalala\n" ;
    $sock->send($response);
    shutdown($sock, 1);
}
```

Client code (tested against above server):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Socket::INET;

my $port = 9040;
my $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerAddr  => 'localhost',
                                 PeerPort  => $port,
                                 Proto     => 'tcp');

if ($sock) {
    my $server_IP = $sock->peerhost();
    my $server_port = $sock->peerport();
    print "\n Connected to $server_IP $server_port \n";

    # initiate protocol
    $sock->autoflush(1);
    print $sock "OK\n";

    my $data;
    $sock->recv($data, 1024);
    print $data;

    shutdown($sock, 1);
}
```

Output from server:

```
Listening on port 9040 ...

 Connected from 127.0.0.1 36106 
OK

Listening on port 9040 ...
```

Output from client:

```
 Connected to 127.0.0.1 9040 
oohlalala
```

Comment: Thanks @Stefan. 
So i see that the strings need to end with \n character. 
Also using this the server stays up listening, but once the client sends the data it disconnects on the second iteration, with the error " cannot determine the peer address ". How do i make this run indefinitely (till ctrl +c).
also this uses hardcoded strings, how would i send user input? 
Meanwhile you've mentioned im using send/recv, is there anything else i should be using ?

Comment: *So i see that the strings need to end with \n character* -- Easy enough to test, but the answer is no. The most important thing to know about sockets is: when you send data over a socket, the data can be split into multiple chunks. The read() in the server merely blocks until it has read a total of 1024 bytes--or the other side closes the socket, in which case read() returns what it has read so far.  That means the server won't read the whole string if the string is longer than 1024 bytes.  It doesn't matter if the string contains newlines or not--the newlines have no affect on read().

Comment: *also this uses hardcoded strings, how would i send user input -- Write a program--without using sockets--that gets user input and prints it out.

Comment: I do not think that the `\n` matter as the code uses `autoflush()`. The problem was that your protocol was "broken", i.e. both were waiting and no side initiated the protocol. This is not a Perl issue, it would have happened in any other language too.

Comment: You are correct. "As is" the server will only handle one request from the client and go back to listening for the next connect.

You will need to hand-off the socket returned by `accept()` to a parallel running "process" that runs the protocol for that socket. There are several options how to do that: (a) `fork()`, i.e. a separate child process, (b) create a thread or (c) an event loop using `IO::Select` or `IO::Poll` to listen to a set of sockets, i.e. the listen + N accepted sockets. You'll need to decide what is applicable to your scenario

Comment: Another alternative is to use POE, i.e. `POE::Component::Server::TCP`

Comment: *I do not think that the \n matter as the code uses autoflush()*.-- I don't understand how newlines and autoflush() have anything to do with each other.

Comment: When an output handle is in "cooked" mode `\n` cause a flush. With `autoflush()` the handle is flushed after every write